# How to load Custom Created view from XIB file and add to StackView

Tags: swift, xib, uistackview, loadnibnamed

I have XIB file in which there is class of type UIView, and I wont to load that XIB in root ViewController:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
// MARK: - Variables


// MARK: - IBOutlets

@IBOutlet private weak var mainStackView: UIStackView!


// MARK: - LifeCycle Methods

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let view = CustomView.instanceFromNib() {

    let view = CustomView.instanceFromNib() as! CustomView
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }   
}
```

}

import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

```
static let id = "CustomView"


@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

static func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "UserReview", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundImageView.'

Answer (score 0):

Did you File owner for Xib file ?? assign `CustomView` class to Xib File's Owner

[image]